# Why has making my carousel narrower created glitchy transition between slides?

Tags: css, class, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm want my carousel to be a certain size (not sure what size until I play about, but certainly not width: 100%) and also to be centred horizontally in the page.

My new CSS rule has made the carousel smaller and central, but now the slides do not move automatically. The ol with class "carousel-indicators" works fine, so I can select and successfully move to each slide manually.

This same CSS has seemingly removed the click functionality of my next/prev arrows. Even stranger, when I click my next arrow, the page 'smooth-scrolls' down the page a little. Thanks in advance :)

Here is the code....

HTML:

```
<div id="event-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-right="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner" roll="listbox">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/pioneeringSpirit.png" alt="Temporary structures built on the Pioneering Spirit catamaran">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Pioneering Spirit</h3>
                                    <p>Weeks at sea produced thousands of square meters of temporary hospitality structures.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/rugbyWorldCup.png" alt="Main structure for England's Rugby World Cup.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Rugby World Cup</h3>
                                    <p>Twickenham is part of the White Rose Crew calander, but this year was special.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/thales.png" alt="A three story structure for Farnborough Airshow.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Thales</h3>
                                    <p>Our favourite biannual build of the worlds largest airshow.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/masterpiece.png" alt="Masterpiece Arts Fair, Chelsea.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Masterpiece</h3>
                                    <p>We are proud to be an integral part of this incredible transformation year in, year out.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/fieldHospital.jpg" alt="Emergancy hospital built in the Pricipality Stadium.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Emergancy Covid-19 Field Hospital</h3>
                                    <p>Helping turn The Pricipality Stadium into Wales largest hospital in just 10 days.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#event-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#event-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">next</span>
                            </a>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner {
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    $('#event-carousel').carousel({
      interval: 8000
    });
    $('#event-carousel').carousel('cycle');

});
```

Comment: Please include a working snippet which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for getting back to me.

I have edited my post so you can see my HTML.

Does this suffice? I'm very stuck and really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Normally a carousel is powered by some JS, this is missing for your post. Also it's generally not a good idea to change CSS for the carousel part, since this will most likely break the behaviour. Change the container of the carousel to adjust the carousel size itself.

Comment: I have also applied my CSS from 'carousel-item' to 'carousel-inner', which has brought my next/prev arrows back within the image and stopped the 'glitchy' effect when they slide, so that has solved two problems, but it has added another. Now the slides don't run automatically. I have edited my post for the new circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, I've added JS code now.

I'll play around with the containers, but if you see something wrong with the new code please let me know. Just know that it works perfectly when stretched to the full width of the page.

Comment: I've removed the CSS and the problems have persisted, even though it was working fine before. I'm so confused.

Comment: I've played about with it and encountered new problems, so to make things less complicated I have posted the new issues with the edited code here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244225/why-have-my-prev-next-buttons-stopped-functioning-on-bootstrap-carousel