# Why have my prev/next buttons stopped functioning on bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I had made a fully functioning carousel, but for some reason the prev/next buttons have ceased to slide the images. Instead the browser just thinks I have clicked anywhere on the carousel and it therefore smooth scrolls until it is vertically central in the page. I'm really bashing my head against a wall playing with it and appreciate any and all help.

Here is the code...

HTML:

```
<section id="ourWork" class="container">
                <article>
                    <h2>Premier Events and World Class Projects</h2>
                    <p>White Rose Crew are commited to realising the worlds most renound public and private events, from the Olympic Games and the colossal Farnborough Airshow to NATO Summits and UN Climate Conferences.<br><br>But we don't stop there. Our expertise repeatedly finds us at the forefront of inovation, filling sporting arenas with emergancy mediacal facilities to fight the Coronavirus pandemic and erecting structures at sea on the worlds largest oceanic vessle.</p>
                    <!--Put carousel here-->
                    <div id="event-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-right="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            <li data-target="#event-carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner" roll="listbox">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/pioneeringSpirit.png" alt="Temporary structures built on the Pioneering Spirit catamaran">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Pioneering Spirit</h3>
                                    <p>Weeks at sea produced thousands of square meters of temporary hospitality structures.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/rugbyWorldCup.png" alt="Main structure for England's Rugby World Cup.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Rugby World Cup</h3>
                                    <p>Twickenham is part of the White Rose Crew calander, but this year was special.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/thales.png" alt="A three story structure for Farnborough Airshow.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Thales</h3>
                                    <p>Our favourite biannual build of the worlds largest airshow.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/masterpiece.png" alt="Masterpiece Arts Fair, Chelsea.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Masterpiece</h3>
                                    <p>We are proud to be an integral part of this incredible transformation year in, year out.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="./recources/images/fieldHospital.jpg" alt="Emergancy hospital built in the Pricipality Stadium.">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Emergancy Covid-19 Field Hospital</h3>
                                    <p>Helping turn The Pricipality Stadium into Wales largest hospital in just 10 days.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#event-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#event-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">next</span>
                            </a>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>
```

JS:

```
$('#event-carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000
    });
    $('#event-carousel').carousel('cycle');
```

Comment: you have only one id="event-carousel" on your page?

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for responding. 100% yes, only 1.

I just removed the JS (which is only determining the carousel speed anyway) and the problem is persistent.